# language neutral interview

Tags: language-agnostic

what exactly does language neutral interview mean?

do they just check for my OOPs/Other concepts or actually check how good my programming skills are?
during the interview what exactly is expected out of me?

any ideas?
-Ivar

Comment: Oh I should add, Good Luck at the interview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some possibilities-

- coding/solving algorithms in psuedocode. Or in any language of your choice.
- (similar to the above) general knowledge of data structures.
- general architecture questions
- dumb logic problems (i.e. "the fewest weighings to find the one ball in 8 that's different", etc.etc)

Mostly I think it means that they're more interested in your problem solving skills than in specific syntax or detailed knowledge of specific libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I think they'll test how you go about solving problems rather than actually writing code.

Something like making a robot move around a field and how would you store information and when the robot is lost and you deploy the next one how would you avoid the last square that previous one was on?

They'll be looking for Interfaces, Object diagrams etc w/out actually coding to a language.

Also point out how your model can be expanded so that the robot not only has a move method but also a cook toast method for future expansion.

Maybe emply a good MVC model for the above.

All this is subjective of course and may be totally wrong. :)

**edit**

the point here is to find out how you think rather than whether you have read and digested a coding language.  anyone can sprout acronyms but not everyone can solve problems.

Comment: So, AFAIK there are two computers: 1 with the interviewer and other with the candidate. Now, what do do they do on the computer? Write/type what?

Comment: Where did you get the information from that there are 2 computers?

Comment: Ah, ok.  In that case all i can do is shrug my shoulders

Comment: Maybe they're going to play World of Warcraft?  Possibly they'll just cut to the chase and play a bit of Doom II deathmatch.

Comment: Hey now wouldn't that be the most awesome interview ever?

Answer (score 1):

I think, that they will see how well your code is organised....
Building the data model may use inheritance or composition or association. 
Eg. in case of c++, we can have **inheritance** like:

```
class Base{};
class Derived:public Base{};
```

Other thing is **association**:

```
class X{}
class Y{
X *a;  //you have pointer to class X
};
```

**Composition:**

```
class X{}
class Y{
X a;    //you have object of class X
};
```

So it depends which way you implement what they have told you to as complexity vary according to that...All languages provide these in some or the other way. They just see how well you **design your class and make code human readable**.